# Setting a "click" method to execute right away

Tags: c#, methods

I have a working method

```
something_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    code
}
...
```

It of course executes after someone clicks the element. What I need to do is, to execute this method immediately after the element appears on the screen (it is `StripStatusLabel`). I have tried just to add a call of the method to beginning of the code, but it did nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`Button.PerformClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) on your button in a [`Form.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx)  event handler.

You might also want to consider moving that logic into its own method, and call that method from both the button handler and the `Load` event, as this will be more clear.  (It's obviously code you want triggered on more than just a "button click").

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what framework you are targeting (WPF vs Winforms) you might be able to handle the Load event instead. It triggers when the element appears on screen.

Answer (score 0):

It's not best practice to fire a form event which would normally be originated from teh user.  In the sense, you are trying to "fake" the click.  Think of the future debugging, or of the colleague who might inherit your project.  When inspecting code you would expect something_Click to only be fired when there is a click on "something".

A better solution is to put the "code" part in your snip into a method whose name reflects what it really does.

They you may fire this method in different areas. Fire it at the click, at the load, anywhere.

```
something_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoStuff();
}

OnAppearToScreen()
{
    DoStuff();
}

DoStuff()
{
    //code that actually does stuff
}
```

Later on, when you want to check when "the stuff" was done to your object, you can easily tell by code inspection.